# How to correctly have or extract the created datetime for a recorded video for a smart CCTV camera (TP Link - Tapo TC70)?

Tags: video, metadata, microsoft-file-explorer, surveillance

For starters, I would like to introduce first the smart CCTV camera I use which is the **Tapo TC70 from TP Link**.

I am using its feature to record continuously. I set the scheduled recording from 5:00PM-6:00PM then another at 9:00PM-10:00PM. When I viewed the metadata in Windows File Explorer of the recorded .mp4 video file in the micro-SD card installed on the unit, the created and modified datetime were exactly the same. The case is similar from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evrL_wGrPqs) I followed which shows the problem.

[image: problem]

I would like to get at least the correct created datetime which my project needs. Do you have an idea as to why this occurs and suggestions on how I can fix it or work my way around it?

I haven't tried anything so far yet as I am out of ideas on how to fix it or work my way around it.

Comment: Look at the Properties->Details tab to see if there is a "Media created" created entry.  Also, it appears that the filename holds the correct timestamp, same as your video link.  Any reason not to parse the filename to get the correct date/time?